# Why in ASP.NET is a button click event executes when page is refreshed?

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP.Net Web Site I have a button.When I click the button and then reload the page via browser,the click event of the button fires.Where is a problem,please help me.

Comment: Are you referring to a postback? The question is a bit vague.

Comment: Could we have a bit more information about the actual problem?  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No,from the button on the browser.

Comment: It's not a problem. When you reload the page - all actions will be occured again.

Comment: Maybe I'm being bitter, but how does a question that requires guessing as to the actual problem get 6 upvotes?

Comment: You can avoid this by disabling `AutoPostBack` like this  `AutoPostBack="False"` as button property

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand correctly.

You have a web form with a button.

You push the button which causes a post back and the event handler for the button press to execute.

Then you hit refresh and the page has the button event handler execute again.

The reason for this is your refreshing the last information sent to the server.  Which is the button click information in the __doPostback.  This is why you are seeing the event of the button fire again.

Here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Detecting_Refresh.aspx) talking about how to detect a refresh over a postback.

Comment: @Noro there is an article that I linked in the answer.

Comment: You can avoid this by disabling `AutoPostBack` like this  `AutoPostBack="False"` as button property –

Answer (score 4):

It's because clicking that button sends a POST request to your page. The POST data is kept in the http headers and when you refresh, it's sent again to server.

Your browser should warn you when you try to refresh the page.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. When you click a server side button (with the `runat="server"` attribute), a click will cause a postback and the button click event will fire.

If you want some client side behaviour, you need to use the `OnClientClick` attribute, as described in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227426.aspx) MSDN article (How to: Respond to Button Web Server Control Events in Client Script).

Answer (score 4):

If this is really important for someone, then they can refresh the page again through a Response.Redirect(). This is the easiest solution that I have been able to find.

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to solve this issue is to redirect your page to some url or refresh your current page using Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was solved by putting the button as asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger of the updatePanel.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh Part of your page then put the control inside the `UpdatePanel` if the control causes `PostBack`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" 
          onClick="uploadAttachmentToList" runat="server" 
          ID="btnUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Upload" 
        />
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```