# Button click event handler fired on page refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net control, which seems to fire the button click event handler on a page refresh. Why does this happen and how could I avoid it?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a page with an ASP:Button and you've clicked the button once for the page to post-back. And then after the post back every time you hit F5 or Refresh the "Click" event happens?

Comment: Not sure about the postback bit, the button just does some logic and writes to the response stream thereafter. but after the code is finished, if I do a manual refresh of the page in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason for this is your refreshing the last information sent to the server. Which is the button click information in the __doPostback. This is why you are seeing the event of the button fire again.

Here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Detecting_Refresh.aspx) talking about how to detect a refresh over a postback.

*For your quick reference, this information is copy pasted from [Why in ASP.NET is a button click event executes when page is refreshed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2379754/500725)*

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this and this works for me -

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            Session["update"] = Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["update"] = Session["update"];
    }

    protected void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (Session["update"].ToString() == ViewState["update"].ToString())
            DisplayInfo();
    }

    private void DisplayInfo()
    {
        // Do what ever thing you want to do
        Session["update"] = Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());  
    }
```

see [This](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread11797-avoid-button-click-event-from-firing-when-page-refresh-occurs-in-aspn.aspx) for more details

Comment: This worked great for me. Just had to add   base.OnPreRender(e);

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the C# solution that stops the click event handler fired on page refresh:**

```
//Web browser refresh fires the last event (ex. button click) again. 
//the following code prevents this action by detecting the Page refresh.

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ViewState["postGuids"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session["postGuid"] = ViewState["postGuids"].ToString();
}
else
{
    if (ViewState["postGuids"].ToString() != Session["postGuid"].ToString())
    {
        IsPageRefresh = true;
    }
    Session["postGuid"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    ViewState["postGuids"] = Session["postGuid"].ToString();
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPageRefresh) //only perform the button click actions if page has not been refreshed
    { 
        //Normal actions as per button click
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just how the browsers work.
On hitting F5, the page refresh causes the last called server side event to GET/POST again. In this case its the button click event.
One way to prevent this from happening is to use Response.Redirect("same_page") to the same page after the event logic. This will force the page to reload and thereafter doing any further page refreshes would not call the button click event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how any server code such as the above copes with detecting repeated refreshes, which users might do if they see something unexpected.  I've had a go at this sort of approach and  after wasting an hour or so decided the simplest way to avoid this is to use Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), True) at the end of the event button(s) code behind to reload the page.  I think this might result in additional network traffic but it is simple.