# ASP.NET Button Click Events Repeat

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a requirement that the current browser window refreshes at regular intervals to keep the current session active.  Below is the JavaScript code that is refreshing the page every 5 minutes.

```
<script language="javascript">
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 300000);
</script>
```

It accomplishes the task, but I am noticing that button click events repeat the function at every page refresh.  A simple example is provided below.  On button click, execute MyFunction();

```
        protected void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyFunction();
    }
```

With a 5 minute page refresh interval, the MyFunction() is executing every five minutes.

[image]

It seems to only happen for button click events.  I changed the interval from 10 seconds to 5 minutes, and the same result is observed; however, it does not seem to happen 100% of the time.

Is there a better way to auto-refresh an ASP.NET page to keep the session active that can avoid this issue, or a way to mitigate the problem being described?  It seems like the event is cached and re-executed upon each page refresh, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: The most simple implementation that met my needs after sifting through all of the relative posts can be seen here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379720/why-in-asp-net-is-a-button-click-event-executes-when-page-is-refreshed/2379754#2379754;  i.e, adding the Response.Redirect() after all button click events have taken place. 

        protected void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Response.Redirect("https://mysite/");
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer might be the same as posted [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf85GlkIb5AhXUJUQIHbkCAkIQFnoECAUQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9556089%2Fbutton-click-event-handler-fired-on-page-refresh%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DThe%2520reason%2520for%2520this%2520is%2Ca%2520refresh%2520over%2520a%2520postback.&usg=AOvVaw0uyL9vvk-uNc8RLLc5IOs_)

> The reason for this is your refreshing the last information sent to the server. Which is the button click information in the __doPostback. This is why you are seeing the event of the button fire again.